# Incorrect derivative of a circle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As a note, I am a beginner calc student. I put the equation of a circle in "y equals form" like this:

$y= \sqrt{25-x^2}$

Using 5 as the radius for no particular reason. When I take the derivative I use the chain rule and get:

$y'= \frac{1}{2} (25-x^2)^{-1/2} - 2x$

But when I graph the result, the derivative does not reflect the slope of the circle. The slope of the tangent line at x=$\pm$5 should approach -$\infty$ at positive and negative 5 but the graph of the derivative doesn't reflect that. Did I take the derivative incorrectly or is the graph not correct? I don't see where I went wrong. [image]

Comment: The correct derivate is $\frac{-x}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$

Comment: Without checking your calculations, the derivative you wrote does give $1/0$ for $x=\pm 5$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD In fact the function is not differentiable at $x_0=\pm 5$

Comment: @Peter I didn't want to be so needlessly technical about it, saying that the derivative yields  infinity at $\pm 5$ was to be understood as $y'\to \pm\infty$ when $x\to \pm 5$ (taking lateral limits, etc) : p.

Answer (score 1):

Please be more careful with your notation.  This is what you should have before simplifying:
$$ y' = \frac12 (25-x^2)^{-1/2} \cdot (-2x)$$

When you say $ \displaystyle y' = \frac12 (25-x^2)^{-1/2} -2x$, the $-2x$ gets interpreted as subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that your derivative is:
$y'= \frac{1}{2} (25-x^2)^{-1/2} - 2x.$

This does not quite follow the chain rule. Under the chain rule you need to multiply the inner derivative instead of adding it. As a result you actually want to multiply the first part by $-2x$ which gives the proper derivative of:
$y' = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{25 - x^2}}.$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that careless mistake

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of assistance. Hope that it helped.